# When does HTTP nw call takes time in "Stalled" or "Initial Connection" in chrome? Can these states create multiple threads for same request?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, google-chrome, ssl, connection

I have an application using angular as client and Java (Springboot) as back end. Sometimes for some random network calls the waterfall get stuck in "Stalled" or in "Initial Connection" state. and when this happens, I have observed in my log4j logs that for same request multiple threads are being created. Which results in delayed response.
For same request when it is triggered again and it is not stuck in these sections, it retrieves data in milliseconds.
[Waterfall state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IL0eb.png)
[Logs-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoGBU.png)

Checked Angular and Java logic but nothing seems to be wrong there as it is working fine for other nw calls and this issue is sporadic

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience in my Angular App.
Turns out the request was waiting for the initial request to respond and use it as a cache.

Try adding these to request headers if it works

```js
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store',
            'Pragma': 'no-cache'
          })
```

Hope this helps